# Динамическая нумерация строк таблицы

Tags: jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте! У меня код, который удаляет фото из базы динамически через Ajax. И есть таблица, в которой выводятся фото из базы.

```
<table class="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                      <th class="number">№</th>
                      <th class="thumb">Фото</th>
                      <th class="album_name">Название фото</th>
                      <th class="album_action">Действие</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>2.</td>
                  <td class="thumb centr"><img class="delalbumimg" src="http://20dord.loc/gallery/35_2015-08-18/35_2015-08-18_9.jpg" rel="1" alt="35_2015-08-18_9.jpg"></td>
                  <td class="album_title centr">35_2015-08-18_9.jpg</td>
                  <td class="photo_action centr">
                  <span class="small howtodelbase">Для удаления картинки кликните на ней</span></td>
                </tr><tr style="display: none;">
                  <td>3.</td>
                  <td class="thumb centr"><img class="delalbumimg" src="http://20dord.loc/gallery/35_2015-08-18/35_2015-08-18_10.jpg" rel="1" alt="35_2015-08-18_10.jpg"></td>
                  <td class="album_title centr">35_2015-08-18_10.jpg</td>
                  <td class="photo_action centr">
                  <span class="small howtodelbase">Для удаления картинки кликните на ней</span></td>
                </tr>
```

Как видите каждая строка нумеруется. В данном случае я удалили первую фотографию. Мне нужно, чтобы при удалении фотографии нумерация автоматически менялась. Вывод номеров строк я сделал:

```
<script>
                var l = $("table tr").length;
                for(var i=1; i<=l; i++){
                  $('.table tbody tr').each(function(i) {
                    $(this).find('td:first').text(i+".");
                  });
                }
            </script>
```

Но этот код работает только при загрузке страницы.

Comment: Этот же код нужно сделать после успешного `ajax`. ps. а зачем так мудрено? просто `$('.table tbody tr').each(function(i) { ...` работать не будет разве?

Comment: Работает. По моей задумке, скрипт должен был посчитать число строк и добавить нумерацию. Вот и написал. Спасибо.

Comment: я про то, что `for(var i=1; i<=l; i++){` не обязательно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А так не работает разве?

```
function updateTableNumeration() {
    $('.table tbody tr').each(function(i) {
          $(this).find('td:first').text(i+".");
    });
}    


$.ajax({
    success: function (res) {
        updateTableNumeration();
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. Заработало. Я это пробовал. Но при загрузке не выводились номера строк. Чуть изменил и все встало на свои места.

Comment: А если на странице несколько таблиц с одинаковым классом?

Comment: @Александр Присвойте таблице id

Answer (score 0):

Я в jquery не селен, и возможно ответ корявый. У меня на странице может быть неопределенное количество таблиц. В этом случае предыдущий ответ не сработает.

```js
function updateTableNumeration() {
    for (z = 0; z < $('table').length; z++) {
        $('.table_'+z+' tbody tr').each(function(i) {
            var number = i + 1;
            $(this).find('td:first').text(number+"");
        });
    }
}

$("body").on('click', '.updateTable', function() {
  updateTableNumeration();
});
```

```css
.button{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: #C0CCDA;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFF;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.button:hover{
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #98A1AC;
    color: #FFF;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Таблица 1</h3>
<table class="table_0" border="1">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <td>№</td>
          <td>Название</td>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Название 1-1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Название 2-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Название 3-3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h3>Таблица 2</h3>
<table class="table_1" border="1">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <td>№</td>
          <td>Название</td>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Название 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Название 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Название 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<a class="button updateTable">Обновить</a>
```